# How to use Softmax Activation function within a Neural Network

Tags: python, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

Understanding until now- An activation function is applied on the neuron.What goes inside the function is the sum of each(connected-neuron-value*connected-weights).A single value enters the function,single value is returned from it. The above understanding works fine with *tanh* and *sigmoid* .
 Now I know how softmax works and it sums the values and everything other related to it.What confuses me is that *softmax* takes an array of numbers, I start questioning what are the sources of these numbers which forms the array ?

The following picture gives more insight into the question

[image]

Comment: Softmax is used for multiclass classification problems, where you have multiple output neurons (one per class). If you only have one output neuron it does not make to use softmax, you would normally use (for classification) a regular sigmoid activation or similar.

Comment: @jdehesa yes I am aware of that, please assume the above picture has three output neurons,correct me if I am wrong the number of output neurons wouldnot matter calculating each hidden layer softmax activated value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Softmax works on an entire layer of neurons, and must have all their values to compute each of their outputs.

The softmax function looks like `softmax_i(v) = exp(v_i)/sum_j(exp(v_j))`, where v would be your neuron values (in your image, `[0.82, 1.21, 0.74]`), and `exp` is just `exp(x) = e^x`. Thus, `exp(v_i)` would be `[2.27, 3.35, 2.096]`. Divide each of those values by the sum of the entire vector, and you get `[0.29, 0.43, 0.27]`. These are the activation outputs of your neurons.

This is useful because the values add up to 1 (forgive the rounding errors in the example above that sum to 0.99... you get the idea), and thus can be interpreted as probabilities, e.g., the probability that an image is one particular class (when it can only belong to one class). That's why the computation needs to know the values of the entire vector of neurons, and can't be computed if you only know the value of a single neuron.

Note that, because of this, you don't usually have another layer after the softmax. Usually, the softmax is applied as the activation on your output layer, not a middle layer like you show. That said, it's perfectly valid to build a network the way you show, you'll just have another weight layer going to your single output neuron, and you'll have no more guarantee about what that output value might be. A more typical architecture would be something `2 neurons -> 3 neurons (sigmoid) -> 4 neurons (softmax)` and now you'll have the probability that your input value falls into one of four classes.

Comment: Thanks a lot @scnerd for the elaborate ans